# git レポジトリの内部にいる状態からトップレベルでコマンドを実行したい

Tags: git

git レポジトリ内部で作業していたとします。プロジェクトに関するもろもろの実行コマンドは、基本的にプロジェクトのトップレベルから実行されることを想定しています。

例: make, rails, etc

レポジトリのどこで作業していようが、トップレベルでコマンドを実行できれば、わざわざ cd する手間がなくてうれしいなと考えました。これを実現する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git の alias を利用できます。以下の設定を `~/.gitconfig` に記載します。

```
[alias]
    exec = !sh -c 'exec \"$@\"' $(which sh)
```

これにより、例えば rails プロジェクトのどこにいても、以下が実行できます。 (サブモジュールなど、サブ git レポジトリは想定外ですが。。)

```
git exec rake db:migrate
```